# Is it problematic if wolkenkit (or any) event-sourced events are unstructured?

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

It seems a bit odd to me that events are not structured in [Wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit). Coming from the Commanded library in Elixir, one of the first things I did after event-storming was to create my Command and Event types. I understand this is how js traditionally behaves, but just having it just defined in the aggregate will take some getting used to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is it problematic […]?"

Well, this is hard to answer, since it highly depends on your (subjective) definition of *problematic*. Basically, you already have the answer by yourself:

> "I understand this is how js traditionally behaves […]"

That.

To get a better understanding of how commands and events in [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) are structured internally, you might be interested in having a look at the npm module [commands-events](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commands-events), which contains the basic data types.

From my very own experience (10 years of C#, 7 years of JavaScript) I can tell you that the missing static type system of JavaScript was never a problem for me, but this is just my highly personal experience.

As you said, it may take some time to get used to it, but you gain an incredible flexibility by this as well.

HTH

*Please note that I am one of the developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*